# Have you ever seen usage of <span> like this?

Tags: html

```
<span content="2010-01-08 21:35:12" property="dc:date">
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be XHML with [**Dublin Core**](http://www.dublincore.org) metadata, a set of metadata field standards.

In HTML, Dublin Core info is used in `meta` and `link` elements only, and I can not find any instance where the data is validly used in a span element. Also, the `content` attribute is not valid in HTML. 
See [**Expressing Dublin Core in HTML/XHMTL meta and link elements**](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcq-html/).

The case is different with XHTML: As @tomlog points out in his comment, the notation you quote is used in this [**example on Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa#Examples_of_RDFa).

Comment: Wikipedia does have an example under its RDFa article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa#Examples_of_RDFa

Comment: Cheers @tomlog, clarified and added the link to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't standard tags, but they are probably used by some javascript on the page that can search based on those properties, or they are akin to comments that the programmer is inserting in the html output.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it appears to be meta-information for whatever goes within the span, or it's storing values for Javascript to use at a later time, or both.

Seeing the "dc" makes me think that there may be more crucial bits that aren't included in your example.

Answer (score 1):

It's a kind of meta data implementation. "dc" stands for [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/documents/dces/) which is a meta data implementation standard.

The appropriate software that can read these meta tags will know to look for a span element and then use the property and content attributes to retrieve the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

`property="dc:date"` is a [Dublin Core](https://validator.schema.org/) Metadata tag of type date. It makes the data in that span, machine readable using [RDFa](https://validator.schema.org/) semantics. Google/ other crawlers can read that info and index it appropriately for searching and relating to other documents. You can test a sites metatdata [here](https://validator.schema.org/).

The inclusion of the DC tag in a span is very common.